# End play if database does not exits

Tags: ansible

I have created the following playbook, to check if a database exists:

```yaml
- name: Check database exits
  shell: |
    mysql -hmysqlhost -uroot -ppassword -e "show databases" | egrep db"
  register: mysql_exist
  
- name: Show database
  debug:
    msg: "{{ mysql_exist.stdout }}"
```

My idea is to finish the playbook if the database does not exist and show a message, I tried this but it does not work, otherwise I should continue to the next task.

```yaml
- name: Check database exits
  shell: |
    mysql -hmysqlhost -uroot -ppassword -e "show databases" | egrep db"
  register: mysql_exist

- name: End Playbook If database not exits.
   meta: end_play
   when: mysql_exist == 0

- name: Show database
  debug:
    msg: "{{ mysql_exist.stdout }}"

## other tasks
```

How can I create a playbook to check if a database exists and if it does not exist, it must display the message `The database does not exist` and finish the playbook without running other tasks?

Comment: 1) Please ban "does not work" from your vocabulary on SO. Explain the result you get, the one you expect and the debug actions your have already taken. 2) Please debug the content of `mysql_exist` to understand that it will never be equal to 0 since it is a dict which contains several keys (like `sdtout`, `stdout_lines`, `stderr`....) 3) You should not use a shell task when a [specific module exists](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/mysql/mysql_db_module.html#ansible-collections-community-mysql-mysql-db-module).

Comment: I am creating a playbook to check if a database exists and if it does not exist I must display the message "The database does not exist" and finish the playbook without running other tasks.

Comment: Summarizing your existing question in a comment does not make it a good question (see [How to ask](/help/how-to-ask)), does not give any new info about what happens exactly, what you expect instead and your current debug steps, and does not fix at all the fact your making a test on a var which will never succeed since you did not have a single look at what it looks like.

Comment: @pi314  dont forget to close your question by validationg and upvoting the right answer for you..

Answer (score 1):

if you want to show a message if playbook has to finish, use a block:

(you dont show the output of your register when a db doesnt exist so, i suppose your test in when condition is ok!!)

```
- block:
    - name: "end play "
      debug:
        msg: "db doesnt exist"

    - meta: end_play
  when: mysql_exist == 0
```

so the playbook is finished after the message displaying

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to show the message? Stopping the playbook already happens automatically if `egrep` does not find anything, because it exits with a non-0 code.

Playbook:

```
---
- hosts: srv1
  become: True
  tasks:
    - name: x
      shell: "echo nope | egrep dbname"
    - name: good
      shell: "echo very much"
```

Output (notice how "good" is not executed):

```
PLAY [srv1] *******************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [x] **********************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [srv1]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": "echo nope | egrep dbname", "delta": "0:00:00.005942", "end": "2022-02-09 15:56:56.726828", "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 1, "start": "2022-02-09 15:56:56.720886", "stderr": "", "stderr_lines": [], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}

PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************************************************************************
srv1                       : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

It could be approximated with something like this:

```
    - name: x
      shell: "echo nope | egrep dbname || { echo Database not found && false; }"
```

Which gives:

```
TASK [x] ***********************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [srv1]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": "echo nope | egrep dbname || { echo Database not found && false; }", "delta": "0:00:00.006159", "end": "2022-02-09 15:59:26.176704", "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 1, "start": "2022-02-09 15:59:26.170545", "stderr": "", "stderr_lines": [], "stdout": "Database not found", "stdout_lines": ["Database not found"]}
```